# how to send php email with a html template without html tags?

Tags: php, html, email, templates

How to only send the content without tags?

I'm using the following code to send an email using a html template.

The email is sent but in the email body I get all the HTML tags also (`<div>`, `<p>`.. and so on).

```
    $message    =   array();
    $message['id'] = $booking_id;
    $message['name'] = $order_info[0]->name;
    $message['email'] = $order_info[0]->email;
    $message['address'] = $order_info[0]->address;
    $message['phone'] = $order_info[0]->phone;
    $message['guests'] = $order_info[0]->total_guest;
    $message['summary'] = $order_info[0]->summary;

    $email_to   =   self::has_get_settings('email');
    $subject    =   "New Booking! - Booking ID. " . $booking_id;
    $from       =   $order_info[0]->email;
    $from_name  =   $order_info[0]->name;

    $template = file_get_contents($controller->plugin_path . 'includes/libraries/email_template.html');

    foreach($message as $key => $value)
    {
        $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value, $template);
    }

    $headers    =   'From: ' . $from_name . '<' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers    .=  'Reply-To: ' . $from_name . '<' . $from . '>';

    wp_mail($email_to,
            $subject,
            $template,
            $headers);
```

Comment: you should write text format email for pretty plain view or just use [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for remove html tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your headers try to add:

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
```

Edit: *I'm not sure this will help you, I just noticed you work with a wordpress function instead of the normal php mail() function*

Comment: Good to hear, maybe you also need to add  return path to the header
$headers .= "Return-Path: {$this->getFromName()} <{$this->getFrom()}>\r\n"; The emails from mail() function will end up easly into spambox when the headers are not correct or incomplete. With also this in the header I noticed less complains that the email ended up in there spam

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress sends text mails by default (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

try to add this before calling `wp_mail`:

```
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

and after `wp_mail` is called, add this:

```
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to send well formed HTML email, and second, you need to mention in the email header that the email body formatted as HTML not just plain text:

Add those lines of code:

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

The above tips are general, finally, you need to learn more about WP on how to send HTML email.